# Apache POI formula evaluation not working for Excel IF

Tags: apache-poi

I am running into an odd problem with POI and the formulate evaluator.  I have done this plenty of time, but for some reason the following formula fails and gives me a headache.

Formula:  =IF(B12=0, B9, 0)

In the case of my sheet, B12 is zero and B9 is actually a filled in number.

When I attempt to check for switch(cell.getCachedFormulaResultType()) 
the cell type comes back as CELL_TYPE_STRING.  However the richstringvalue is null.

I then attempt to perform a calculation via:

```
   FormulaEvaluator evaluator =         cell.getSheet().getWorkbook().getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
```

but get a: XmlValueDisconnectedException.

According to the list of supported functions, IF, should be trivial.

Can anyone offer any other suggestion, I am stumped and the exception is meaningless :(

The trace:

```
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlValueDisconnectedException
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.check_orphaned(XmlObjectBase.java:1244)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTDefinedNameImpl.getName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFName.getNameName(XSSFName.java:133)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.getName(XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.java:84)
```

Comment: Are you creating the formula using POI? If so, how? When you create the formula (assuming you're doing it in POI), are you including the "=" sign? If so, there's your issue

Comment: Nope, this is the formula from within the Excel sheet.  All the other simple formulas work, but the IF does not.

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you trying this with? And if it isn't the latest (3.11 beta 2 as of writing), did you try upgrading?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.

In my case, I was invoking workbook.write() before invoking FormulaEvaluator. 
Issue got resolved after the sequence is swapped.

**Working Code:**

```
FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
formulaEvaluator.evaluateAll();

workbook.write(fileOutputStream);
```

**Problematic Code:**

```
workbook.write(fileOutputStream);

FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
formulaEvaluator.evaluateAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add xmlbeans jar file which is in poi library folders.